# Improving first time load of a Production Admin on Rest/React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using `Admin-on-rest` and deploy the production app to `AWS S3`.

I created `Admin-on-rest` app with `create-react-app` in `Admin-on-rest`'s instructions.

To build app: I run this script: `npm run build`

Size of file `main.js` is too big (5 MB). And for the first time load, it takes more than 5 mins. (My internet's speed test is 3MB/s)

Is there any way to reduce the size of `main.js` file?

I'm reading about JS chucking but it's not easy to apply to `Admin-on-rest`

Comment: As you can see on the demo (https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/), the `main.js` is *only* 1.4 MB. You're probably referencing other libs in a non optimized way. Can you share the list of your dependencies ?

Comment: Thanks. AWS SDK and JS-XLSX is too big. I'm trying to use alternative modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. AOR itself has not THAT much of an impact on application size and optimising an app is a very different task.

Following are the steps I took when optimising my in production app from 2.8 MB ish to 400 KB served file size.

1) First step is to know what part of the code is causing bloats. You can do this quite easily with Source Map Explorer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer

2) After identifying the packages/modules you should explore ways of reducing their size on your code. e.g 
Don't do

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

DO

```
import find from 'lodash/find'
```

Reducing unnecessary imports is low hanging easy fruit

3) Check if there are smaller versions of the libraries available that you can plug  in.

For instance moment.js now has moment-mini which tracks the main package and does not have all the internationalisation data in it. That shaved off about 400 KB of the bundle size for me.

4) GZIP GZIP GZIP. The biggest impact on my file size yet.

I was using Nginx to serve my static files and I could simply add a config to it to gzip the package while in transit. Worked super smoothly.

If you are using something like Apache then you can also probably figure out a way to do this.

Another option is to eject from Create React App and then configure webpack to generate gzipped files at build time. This theoretically should lead to even smaller bundles as you can use Tree Shaking during compression. This was my experience just 2 months ago, Create React App might have made some way to inform webpack to gzip the bundle. Do explore that avenue as well.

**This reduced my bundle size down from 1.6 mb to a ~400 kb served file.**

5) Finally, there you can exit React itself and use Preact which is the hot in the market way to reduce bundle size. I haven't used this. But you can try and document your findings, for the benefit of us all.

6) If you need in production app to be even smaller then you will have to look at more advanced strategies such as loading a dashboard/landing page with server side rendering and the rest of the app bundle async when the dashboard gets loaded.

Best of luck.

**Edit on - 26/02/2018**
Just discovered this --> https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

More details here. This does not use the react-loadable and instead teaches you how to use code splitting, which is supported by Create-React-App bootstrapped pages out of the block.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/lazy-loading-routes-in-react

Comment: https://github.com/robertknight/webpack-bundle-size-analyzer is a great tool for that too